Short story about God losing a war with Satan
I read a short story in the seventies in England. In it, God is losing to Satan. To save himself, God "converts" his "body" into trillions and trillions of microscopic pieces and disperses them throughout the Universe, thus ensuring that Satan can never win. Those microscopic particles are the origin of life.
As every form of life reproduces and eventually expires, its "life force" joins with all the others that have gone before to form an immense ball of white light. At the instant of joining the ball of light, every life form becomes part of the collective knowledge and is equipped to understand the meaning of the universe/life.
I'm not absolutely sure about the ball of light et al; I may have imagined that and over the years added it to the story.
Can anyone identify this story?

Does any part of the story involve human characters or the planet Earth, or is the whole story told on a cosmic scale?

I don't recall any human/Earth involvement
